# Altering format of apa6e

Tags: titles, abstract

I am fairly new to LaTeX and am just learning how to use this terrific tool.  Because of this newness I lack the vocabulary to search properly or edit code within LaTeX files.  That places me in a bad spot because there are three things I'd like to perform using LaTeX using `apa6e` but am unable to as the use of `apa6e` gives me the format I want but restricts what I can do:

1. How can I suppress the abstract page from `apa6e`?
2. How can I suppress the author notes in ape6e?
3. How can I suppress the warning generated in `apa6e` when I add `[leavefloats]` to the document class?

I don't know if this is something I do from within my tex editor or if I have to alter the `apa6e` file containing the code for the package.  I'm thinking there's an `apa6e.sty` file that I could alter to bring about these changes.  If that's the case I'd greatly appreciate knowing how to locate and alter this file.  In either case I'd greatly appreciate direction with regard to these alterations.

MWE example (this produces the warning message from the '[leavefloats]'):

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\abstract{This is an example of of an abstract in APA.  }
\begin{document}
\title{A Template for APA Papers}
\shorttitle{APA: A Template}
\author{John}
\authornote{\dots}
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example
\maketitle
\section{Literature Review}
Stuff
\end{document}
```

MWE in which I try to leave out the abstract and author note:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\abstract{This is an example of of an abstract in APA.  }
\begin{document}
\title{A Template for APA Papers}
\shorttitle{APA: A Template}
\author{John}
\authornote{\dots}
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example
\maketitle
\section{Literature Review}
Stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: The **apa6e** class is designed specifically in order to respect the style requested by the American Psychological Association for submissions and, in my opinion, doesn't qualify for an example of good typography. You probably can do with the **article** class, or maybe **amsart**.

Comment: egreg,Thank you for your response. Part of learning a software and the community around that software is the culture and language of that community. Thank you for helping me understand a MWE (I'm quasi familiar with the concept from my interaction with the R community). You were gentle with a newbie. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with egreg's comment about using another document class. However if, for some reason, you must use `apa6e`, then 1., 2., and 3. can be solved by redefining `\maketitle` as implemented in `apa6e.cls`. You, however, don't have to modify the file `apa6e.cls` directly (which, in any case, is never a good practice). You can, for example, make the changes in your `.tex` document by doing the approapriate redefinitions there (and enclosing them with `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` in case the character `@` appears in any of the involved commands.)

Here's a simple `.tex` document showing the necessary redefinition of `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}

\makeatletter
\def\authornote#1{}
\def\abstract#1{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
 \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
 \vspace*{1in}%
 \Centering\@title\\\@author%
 \vfill%
 \ifdefined%
 \apaSIXe@leavefloats{}
  \fi
  \RaggedRight%
 \mspart{\@title}%
}
\makeatother

\title{A simple, correct explanation for every aspect of mental function}
\shorttitle{Psychology: the end}
\author{Over J.~Optimistic\\Pie in the Sky University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
I have discovered a truly remarkable theory which
this example is too small to contain.
\end{document}
```

I have some doubts regarding 1. I assumed that you wanted to get rid of the abstract altogether. If this was not your intent, please let me know.

Comment: Gonzalo- Thank you for your response.  I did what you suggested.  it worked perfectly, but had some side effects.  I am using biblatex with the hyperref package.  The code erases the references from the pdf bookmarks that hyperref creates, though the references and links still work.  Secondly, the rest of the document becomes centered istead of ragged right.  Now for the part I don't understand, when I tried to delete the suggested code I put in MikTex won't run anymore.  Did the code chunk make global changes to the apa6e.cls?  How do I fix this?

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: See my updated answer. 1) Regarding the problem with the document being centered instead of ragged right, that should be solved with the new code (I initially forgot a `\RaggedRight` command that I have added). 2) Regarding the  bookmark for the "References" section, `apa6e.cls` does not produce such a bookmark, (and my modifications don't interfere with the biliography). 3) I don't quite understand the last part of your comment. The code I gave you simply redefines a command implemented in `apa6e.cls`.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: Hmmm... perhaps I know what you meant. With the modification I gave you, you don't have to use the `\authornote` and the `\abstract` commands. If you remove the code I gave you, you'll have to use those commands again; otherwise your document won't compile.

Comment: Additionally the reference problem I was having was unrelated.  I got that one figured out.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: I made a new addition to my code. Now you can use `\authornote` and `\abstract` safely with my code. I redefined simply to do nothing.

Comment: Perfection!  You have solved my woes and I've learned a bit more about how Latex operates.  You were right with both of your last comments.  I appreciate your help.  Thanks to Nathaniel Smith too, he gave advice in an email I sent to him regarding modifying his package.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Since my response seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count. This shows that the answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points (to the author of the answer and to you!)

Comment: I now would like to have the abstract included and have asked for this in a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144685/alter-apa6e-suppress-author-notes-and-fix-floats) if you'd be so kind as to take a look.