# Altering title page : apa6e

Tags: titles, apa6

I am using the `apa6e` package.  I once asked a question ([LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30192/altering-format-of-apa6e)) about altering it and received some code to do so.  I am getting somewhat more comfortable with LaTeX and now have two changes I'd like to make to the title page.  I don't understand how the code worked to alter the title page so I believe studying the code will help me see how the title page is altered.  I'd like to (a) split the title onto two lines after the colon and (b) I'd like to inset a comment at the bottom of the page That is left justified.  Annotated comments would be helpful as I try to understand how to alter the title page.

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%--------------------------
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
 \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
 \vspace*{1in}%
 \Centering\@title\\\@author%
 \vfill%
 \ifdefined%
 \apaSIXe@leavefloats{}
 \fi
 \RaggedRight%
 \mspart{\@title}%
 }
 \makeatother

\title{The super long title: It be broken by LAtex but I'd like to break on the colon}

\shorttitle{SHORT}
\author{Bob}

%\Comment_at_the_bottom_of_page{Presented at a conference}

\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what I wanted with some hacks as I did not get a response.  I'll post the hacks but I'd be interested in knowing more about altering the title page correctly.  I used this in the title page:

```
\newsavebox{\mytitle}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytitle}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \normalfont The super long title: \\ \\ \vspace{.5cm} 
  \normalfont It be broken by LAtex but I'd like to break on the colon
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\title{\usebox\mytitle}


\author{Bob \\
University at Moon \\ \raggedright \vspace{14cm} 
A paper presented at the Burger King in \\ Atlanta, GA at some time. \\
}
```