# Alter apa6e (suppress author notes and fix floats)

Tags: apa-style, apa6

I am trying to use `apa6e` but want to suppress floats warning and suppress author note.  I once received similar help [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30203/8294) but am unable to generalize to now include the abstract.  Learning this will help me to understand more about manipulating `\makeatletter`

1. How can I suppress the author notes in `apa6e`?
2. How can I suppress the warning generated in `apa6e` when I add `[leavefloats]` to the document class?

Here's a MWE of my current setup based on the question I asked before (which does what I want but also suppresses the abstract that I now want):

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\makeatletter
\def\authornote#1{}
\def\abstract#1{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
 \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
 \vspace*{1in}%
 \Centering\@title\\\@author%
 \vfill%
 \ifdefined%
 \apaSIXe@leavefloats{}
  \fi
  \RaggedRight%
 \mspart{\@title}%
}
\makeatother

\abstract{This is an example of an abstract in APA.}

\newsavebox{\mytitle}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytitle}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \normalfont A title: On 2 lines
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\title{\usebox\mytitle}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{People}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Content
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppressing the author note is just

```
\authornote{}
```

The warning about

```
\end occurred when \ifx on line 46 was incomplete
```

is due to a serious bug in `apa6e.cls` which, on line 46 has

```
46 \ProcessOptions\relax
```

but some lines before shows

```
40 \DeclareOption{endnotes}{\def\apaSIXe@endnotes\relax}
41 \DeclareOption{leavefloats}{\def\apaSIXe@leavefloats\relax}
42 \DeclareOption{floatmarkers}{\def\apaSIXe@floatmarkers\relax}
```

which are horribly wrong: the `\def` should be `\let`.

Copy `apa6e.cls` to your working directory and change the offending commands; then write to the maintainers so that they correct the error as soon as possible. There's nothing else one can do about the problem.

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\authornote{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
 \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
 \vspace*{1in}%
 {\Centering\@title\par\@author\par}
 \vfill
 \mspart{\@title}%
}
\makeatother

\abstract{This is an example of an abstract in APA.}

\title{A title\protect\\ on two lines}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{People}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Content
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not the most proficient with LaTeX.  I copied apa5e.cls from [here](http://math.sut.ac.th/lab/software/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6e/apa6e.cls) and change the `\def`s to `\let`s and dropped it in the same directory as the location of the .tex file.  But when I run the abstract does not appear.  Do I need to source the .cls somehow?

Comment: @TylerRinker *You* are redefining `\maketitle` not to show the abstract.

Comment: because of what you said it taught me how to look at the cls, figure out what's going on and change it.  This is better than solving the question.  Thanks a ton.  Much appreciated.